# Open MongoDB to internal IPs

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB running on a Raspberry Pi at my house, and I'm trying to edit the config file so that other computers at my house can connect to it. Here's some numbers:

| Device | IP |
| --- | --- |
| Raspberry Pi | 192.168.1.5 |
| Laptop | 192.168.1.7 |

When I edit `/etc/mongod.conf` to look like this, I can connect from my laptop:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

But, what I *want to do* is this, which should allow my laptop to connect:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.7
```

But this doesn't work. When I run `sudo service mongod restart` it errors and says it exited with status code 48. I looked up error code 48, which is supposed to indicate that the port is already in use, but if I change the `bindIp` property to either `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` it restarts without errors.

How can I bind MongoDB to IPs on my local network?

**Solved:**

User R2D2 in the comments was correct; I needed to use the IP of the host machine, not the IP of the connecting machine. This makes sense, now that I know. Below is the working config - notice the IP listed is the IP of the Raspberry Pi, which is the same IP my dev machines will be pointing to in order to connect.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.5
```

Comment: For this you should use your firewall. Apart from that, the IP may change. Did you enable authentication?

Comment: you must bind to 192.168.0.5 ( the Raspberry Pi IP ) since you are running the mongod in the Raspbery Pi ...

Comment: Questions and Answers are separate fields on Stack Overflow. Please move your  answer to the answer field below, so that the system can recognise that this question is answered (something it cannot do if the answer is edited into the question body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User R2D2 in the comments was correct; I needed to use the IP of the host machine, not the IP of the connecting machine. This makes sense, now that I know. Below is the working config - notice the IP listed is the IP of the Raspberry Pi, which is the same IP my dev machines will be pointing to in order to connect.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.5
```