# mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server - Main PID: 4565 (code=exited, status=48)

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-20.04, linode

my question is similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141447/why-does-the-status-of-mongo-throw-me-code-exited-status-48)

but all the answer of given here are not working for me ? My  `etc/mongod.conf` file like this and start the server

```
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<sameserverIP>,<anotherServerIp>
```

If i run `systemctl status mogod` i got following response:

```
     mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-12-27 14:12:42 +0545; 2min 36s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 5493 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
   Main PID: 5493 (code=exited, status=48)
```

and if i change my `etc/mongod.conf` file like this and restart server

```
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<sameserverIP>
```

then the mongodb server will work fine here is the output of `systemctl status mongod`

```
 mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-12-27 13:47:45 +0545; 10s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 4608 (mongod)
     Memory: 211.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─4608 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

I tried checking journal also using this command `journalctl -u mongod`

```
Dec 27 14:12:42 178-79-149-108.ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 27 14:12:42 178-79-149-108.ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Dec 27 14:12:42 178-79-149-108.ip.linodeusercontent.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This mongo server is installed in linode ubuntu 2020.04 lts from linode marketplace and mongodb version is 5.0.14. i want to give access to only 4 ipaddress in this mongodb can any one help me fix this issue?

Comment: What do you try with `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<sameserverIP>,<anotherServerIp>`? Note, this parameter is **not** referring to the client IP, it is your own IP. Actually, this parameter makes only sense on a computer with multiple network interfaces, then you can define over which interface you can connect to the MongoDB.

Comment: i want to access this database server from only few ip address how to achieve this then?

Comment: Then setup a firewall accordingly, either the internal firewall or an external network firewall. You cannot prevent/allow connection to MongoDB by setting `bindIP` - that's a common misunderstanding of this parameter. There is just one exception: with `bindIP: localhost` you can connect only from local machine (e.g. while maintenance work) and connection from any other host is not possible.